# Split() function giving compile error: Invalid Identifier

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I run this code, it says `TargetText` is an invalid identifier. I have no clue what the problem might be.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim TargetText As String
    TargetText = ""
    TargetText = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text

    Dim strarray() As String
    strarray = TargetText.Split(" ")
End Sub
```

[image: "Invalid Identifier"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are receiving this error is because `TargetText` is a `String` and in VBA a `String` doesn't support the `Split` method (unlike in VB.Net which is where you have possibly seen examples of this working).

To use `Split` is actually not that difficult though:

```
strarray = Split(TargetText, " ")
```

The `Split` function just takes a `String` as the first parameter, and the *delimiter* (the text to split by) as the second parameter.

Here is a link to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function).